# Estimating tracing observation with low probability

Tags: machine-learning, probability, references

### A short version of the question:

```
        y           likelihood
0       161.711019  1.000000
1       163.758187  0.999991
2       293.081999  0.000392
3       293.300179  0.000544
4       293.419239  0.000496
...     ...         ...
3856    480.109953  0.114462
3857    457.955736  0.000998
3858    482.110017  0.000090
3859    483.876531  0.000039
3860    479.902427  0.000019
```

I just need someone to direct me to resources on how to solve this problem. Or even as short as what is the name is this kind of question:

As you can see from the table above, there are y-coordinates and their likelihood accordingly. How do I use a (machine learning) model to *learn the pattern* and *rates of changes (acceleration)* to **estimate and replace the y values with low likelihood**?

---

### More background:

For example, one naive approach will be replacing y values `y_t` with a likelihood of less than 0.8 with the mean of the points before and after it, i.e. `y_t = (y_{t-1} + y_{t+1})/2`. Not only this method has lots of problems such as "What if two points in a row have low likelihood?", but more importantly, it doesn't take any characteristic of the data into account. What if we learn from the data that it's more of a parabola looking curve, as a simple example.

The above data is y coordinates of a mouse's foot on a rotarod observed and generated by [DeepLabCut](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut) (DLC). DLC uses DNN to learn and mark a body part of an object that we specify. Because the mouse is on the rotarod and the camera is only seeing their rear, the foot will sometimes disappear from the frame (going to the front of the rotarod). In which case, DLC gives crazy non-sense value with (thankfully) low likelihood, such as the rows with index 2 or 3865.

(The labellings with likelihood > 0.9 is 50% of the data, as per calculation. The near end of the data gives blizzard values with low likelihood because the mouse fell off from the rotarod.)

Hence, I would like to know the answer to my question posed at the beginning of the post.

I have looked into the followings:

1. Continuous-Time Hidden Markov Model
2. State Space Model
3. GPS tracing
4. Kalman filter

I am still not sure which one's most appropriate. They all don't seem to fit my situation perfectly. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: What exactly does "likelihood" mean and how is it measured?

Comment: Good question. Let me dig into some paper. Also, would some example pictures with low likelihood help?

Comment: Possibly.  The context suggests to me that "likelihood" may be some kind of number produced by the measurement system to indicate a degree of reliability.  I have seen many kinds of systems where such numbers were produced by proprietary (and often undocumented) algorithms.  That doesn't mean the numbers are useless, but in such cases it suggests they should be treated purely as ordinal values. As far as "learn the pattern" goes, you seem to be looking for methods to *impute missing values in time series.*